# Was my edit too short?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I performed a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24138247) yesterday, that got approved by 1 person, and rejected by 2 others. I did not make many changes to it, and as that, may have put unnecessary work on reviewers, but I did make grammatical corrections, and changed the wording of SO as a "forum", to a "site". Was my edit simply not substantial enough, or are there other reasons?

Yesterday, the question had 17 upvotes; today it has 16. I did not vote on the question, but gave an upvote to the comment below it, giving a link to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). The question has persisted for 4 years, with 3 answers, the accepted one from a user with 12 100 points. Based on its other replies, I found others to have accepted the question; and, to be honest, there are many far worse questions than this; I'd rather take down those before going after this; therefore, I improved the question rather than downvoting or flagging it. Was my action wrong?

Comment: "I'm new to CSS, and to this site." Even in its improved form, it's unnecessary to have in a question.

Comment: @JeanneDark Yes, you're correct, especially about "and to this site", but not being familiar with a certain language, set the requirements for answers differently, though CSS might not be one of those languages.

Comment: If I had reviewed it, I would have hit "Accept and Improve" and removed all of the irrelevant fluff from the beginning, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27853884/revisions, and then I would VtC as off-topic and/or too broad.

Comment: @Flimzy Oh, right; I even forgot that "A". Yeah, my edit wasn't that good... I see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was my action wrong?

I don't think so. I don't know why your edit was rejected. I don't think it went far enough, but it did offer minor improvement. If I had seen it in the review queue, I would have accepted the edit, or (more likely) accepted it and improved it, by removing fluff.

So in the future, my advice:

1. Make your edits as substantial as possible. Remove unnecessary phrases like "I'm new", or "Thanks in advance" or "Help appreciated." None of these phrases add any value to the question, and just take away from reader's time.
2. Don't refrain from voting to close off-topic questions, even if they are popular and old.  The site's standards have changed (improved, by most counts) over time, so it's expected that some old content should be cleaned up or closed.

   Keep in mind that a closed question isn't automatically deleted, so googlers can still find the content. It just won't get new answers after being closed.

   Further, if you feel bad about closing a question with good answers, consider marking it a duplicate to a better version of the same question. This way googlers who find the question will be directed somewhere even better.